# django Pagination with Class-Based Views

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How do i create pagination in Django ListView? and i just want that per page have 5 records only

this is my views.py

```
class ArticleListView(ListView):
    model = StudentsEnrollmentRecord
    template_name = 'Homepage/studentsenrollmentrecord_list.html'
    paginate_by = 5
    queryset = StudentsEnrollmentRecord.objects.all()
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
       context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
       return(context)
```

and this is my html search_and_page.html

```
    <table id="customers">
        <tr>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
        {% for article in object_list %}
        <tr  id="myAnchor">
            <td class="grpTextBox">{{ article.username }}</td>
            <td class="grpTextBox">{{ article.Firstname }}</td>
            <td class="grpTextBox">{{article.Email}}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

in web view

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you miss out this

check out this documentation https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/03/how-to-paginate-with-django.html

```
<center>
    {% if is_paginated %}
  <ul class="pagination">
    {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
      <li class="page-item"><a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">&laquo;</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="disabled page-item"><span>&laquo;</span></li>
    {% endif %}
    {% for i in paginator.page_range %}
      {% if page_obj.number == i %}
        <li class="active page-item"><span>{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
      {% else %}
        <li class="page-item"><a href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% if page_obj.has_next %}
      <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">&raquo;</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="disabled page-item"><span>&raquo;</span></li>
    {% endif %}
  </ul>
{% endif %}
</center>
```